# Convert Item Sourcing a ComboBox using a method to markup

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SearchGendersComboBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
                          IsEditable="True"
                          SelectedValuePath="Key"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=GenderId}"

                          />
```

and I am filling it up with this:

```
public void BindComboBoxes()
{            
    SearchGendersComboBox.ItemsSource = new BindingSource(GenderMgr.GetGendersDropDown(true), null);            
    SearchGendersComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

And this is the `GenderMgr`:

```
public class GenderMgr
{

    public static Dictionary<byte, string> GetGendersDropDown(bool isFilterMode = false)
    {
        return GenderDb.RetrieveGendersDropDown(isFilterMode);
    }

}
```

How can I fill up the `ComboBox` using my `GenderMgr.GetGendersDropDown` in markup?

Comment: You won't use a `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource` in a WPF application. Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), especially the *Binding to Collections* chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `BindingSource`, the `ItemsSource` should directly be `GenderMgr.GetGendersDropDown(true)`, i.e. the dictionary. Everything else looks fine.

As for conversion to markup: At some point you need to get objects from somewhere, so there is not much you can do besides maybe using an `ObjectDataProvider` to call the respective data providing method in XAML. Usually you would have some property to hold the items in a view-model, the `ItemsSource` then can still be bound in XAML; as long as the view-model supports change notifications the property then can be assigned at any point the data becomes available.